# How does a spare mixture of experts route each token separately to an expert?

Tags: transformer

As far as I can understand the routing mechanism in the [the sparsely-gated mixture-of-experts layer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06538.pdf) routes each token to its own expert. Considering that the output of the attention layer is a three dimensional tensor(batch_size, seq_len, embd_dim), how does this routing happen especially considering that each batch is supposed to be processed independently?